# How to access "resend" in desktop Outlook in Windows 8 like it can be done in Windows 7

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have used the resend option quite a bit in my desktop version of Outlook in windows 7. It doesn't seem to be in other versions (specifically in windows 8). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2013, you go to File > Resend. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a quick toolbar button equivalent or something you can add to the Ribbon.

There's a solution that involves [VBA scripting and calling that script from a Macro](http://web.archive.org/web/20150306172822/http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/outlook-vba/resend-this-message/). That Macro can be a toolbar item.